# Writing to a file in C not working

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, file-writing

I have the following code, and I keep on getting the "Program has stopped working" error after I have input the characters.

I have done some debugging and found that the issue is in the writing to the file part, however I cannot find the issue.

Can anyone help me? (I'm new to C)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char characters;

printf("Input your characters: ");
scanf("%s", &characters);

FILE *fp = fopen("File.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp, "%s", characters);    
fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: `char characters;` only stores one character.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too basic.

Comment: also this is a crash waiting to happen. You are smashing your stack by writing a random string over it

Comment: @slim (I'm not defending the question, but..) are you sure that's a valid close reason?

Comment: @SouravGhosh this isn't the place for a meta-discussion, but on meta people are generally agreed that there are too many questions based on not knowing the basics, and since there's no ready-made close reason that matches, I've decided to do it this way from now on. SO isn't here for your first week of learning C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `characters` is of type `char` which is not fit to store a *string*. You need to make `characters` as an array.

Essentially, what happens behind the hood is, because of `%s`, the input value (even if a single `char`) gets stored in the memory pointed by the address supplied, but after that, the attempt to store the terminating null, causes out of bound access. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()`, (*emphasis mine*)

> `s` Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.<sup>286)</sup>
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a
> **pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the
> sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically.**

Comment: @DatBoi By either allocating the memory dynamically (which you can easily find out how to do online), or by defining a large char array.